# C++ Translation Phase Confusion

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Can someone explain why the following doesn't work?

```
int main() // Tried on several recent C++ '03 compilers.
{
  #define FOO L
  const wchar_t* const foo = FOO"bar"; // Will error out with something like: "identifier 'L' is undefined."
  #undef FOO
}
```

I thought that preprocessing was done in an earlier translation phase than string literal operations and general token translation.

Wouldn't the compiler be more or less seeing this:

```
int main()
{
  const wchar_t* const foo = L"bar"; 
}
```

It would be great if someone could cite an explanation from the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
#define FOO L\
```

without the trailing `\` there will be a space between `L` and the string on macro substitution. This is from the result of `g++ -E` :

```
const wchar_t* const foo = L "bar";
```

Comment: Make sure to leave a blank line between this definition and the next line, otherwise the macro will be continued. I've used this many times in the past to make multi-line macros.

Comment: Note that this will not work on a conforming preprocessor because a conforming preprocessor is token-based.  The only way to combine two tokens into one (e.g., an `L` and a `"bar"`) is to use the concatenation operator (`##`), which cannot appear as the last token of a replacement list.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to John's answer, I think you could define this the way Microsoft's _T() is defined:

```
#define FOO(x)     L ## x
```

and use it like this:

```
FOO("bar")
```

This will concatenate the L with the text appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this. I already use _T (and friends), just stumbled across this "problem" when messing around with some code.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting means that it is preprocessing your `#define` before it does anything else, it just doesn't know what it ends up meaning (after replacing all `FOO`s with `L`s, it looks for what `L` means and can't figure it out).

The compiler is seeing your second bit of code, it just doesn't know what `L"bar"` means at that point.

Are you sure everything is defined and included properly?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output from the preprocessor (g++ -E)

```
# 1 "ttt.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "ttt.cc"
int main()
{

  const wchar_t *const foo = L "FOO";
}
```

There's a space after your L.